# Passing arguments to includegraphics

Tags: graphics, key-value

I have a multi-page PDF document, which must be 'cut up' and spread across pages. To this end, I would like to have a command defined, something like

```
\newcommand{\flub}[2]{\includegraphics[page=#1,trim=#2]{foo}}
```

later to be put in a for loop, so that if I had proposed trimming

```
\def\marl{1in,1in,1in,1in}
```

I could simply

```
\flub{1,\marl}
```

to get the first page cropped and placed to taste. Of course, this won't work because of some funny business with the keyval package. One might think that a command to the strain of

```
\newcommand{\flub}[4]{\includegraphics[page=1,trim=#1 #2 #3 #4]{foo}}
```

would circumvent the problem, but this still fails to parse (strangely though, this works if I fix three margins).

With only a couple of settings for trimming, one possibility would be to create a series of commands invoking `\setkeys` to change the `trim` option, but my question seems so natural that I wonder if my proposed command `\flub` will work after some very small change.

Comment: Have you looked at the pdfpages package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The argument for `trim` cannot contain commas, as it interferes with the way a key-value list works (they're separated by commas). Also, one has to ensure that the arguments are expanded. The following definition might suffice:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\flub}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\includegraphics[page=#1,trim=#2,clip]{foo}}%
  \x
}

\def\marl{1in 1in 1in 1in}

\begin{document}

\flub{1}{\marl}

\end{document}
```

Note how `\marl` is defined (*without* commas). You can write a parser to extract the elements if you really want to use commas.

Instead of looping to insert pages, consider using [`pdfpages`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) which is meant specifically for this type of multi-page document insertion.